# How to handle Realm transactions on Android

Tags: android, realm, realm-java

In several pieces of sample code out there, I've seen patterns that look like this:

```
try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
  realm.beginTransaction();
  workWithRealmData();
  realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

The question is - is this safe? If the "workWithRealmData()" function throws an exception, the transaction won't be canceled. But we are closing the Realm anyway in the finally of the try-with-resources.

A safer construction might look like the following:

```
try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
  realm.beginTransaction();
  try {
    workWithRealmData();
    realm.commitTransaction();
  } finally {
    if (realm.isInTransaction()) {
      realm.cancelTransaction();
    }
  }
}
```

That looks safer - but also looks significantly nastier to code for all callsites.

So really this boils down to - is it safe to ignore cancelTransaction if the Realm is closed immediately afterwards, or not? If not, what could go wrong?

Comment: If you close the Realm right after then it is safe to ignore the `cancelTransaction`. It does feels a bit unsafe to me though, because if you miss one place then you will block a thread.

Comment: Great - thanks for the confirmation, Christian!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `executeTransaction(Realm.Transaction)` method which automatically cancels the synchronous transaction in case of error.

```
try(Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    r.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
        workWithRealmData();
    });
}
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion - thanks! I'm still curious about the behavior of the original code sample, though. As I understand it, the sample you suggest involves creating a new anonymous class - and is somewhat painful to work with in our unit testing framework, since Realm can't be mocked (last I looked).

Comment: We made all Realm classes non-final in 2.2.2, so you should be able to mock all classes now using Mockito

Comment: If you check the source code for `executeTransaction` it does pretty much what you showed at the top.